# How to disable 1 version of PostgreSQL server without uninstalling it

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have installed PostgreSQL `9.1` and `9.2` on my Ubuntu machine. The postgresql service starts both versions:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
$ * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server  [ OK ]
$ * Starting PostgreSQL 9.2 database server  [ OK ]
```

I'd like to start just `9.2` server but without uninstalling `9.1`, is that possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short version**:
 Replace `auto` with `manual` in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/start.conf`

**Long version**:

Each PostgreSQL cluster in Debian/Ubuntu has a `start.conf` file that controls what `/etc/init.d/postgresql` should do.

This is documented with [pg_createcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html):

```
   STARTUP CONTROL
   The start.conf file in the cluster configuration directory controls the
   start/stop behavior of that cluster’s postmaster process. The file can
   contain comment lines (started with ’#’), empty lines, and must have
   exactly one line with one of the following keywords:

   auto
       The postmaster process is started/stopped automatically in the init
       script.  This is also the default if the file is missing.

   manual
       The postmaster process is not handled by the init script, but
       manually controlling the cluster with pg_ctlcluster(1) is
       permitted.

   disable
       Neither the init script nor pg_ctlcluster(1) are permitted to
       start/stop the cluster. Please be aware that this will not stop the
       cluster owner from calling lower level tools to control the
       postmaster process; this option is only meant to prevent accidents
       during maintenance, not more.
```

Comment: Actually it should be 'disabled', not 'disable' - so says the start.conf file itself. Should I start the server some other way that 'sudo service postgresql start'? cause this way the manual/disabled cluster still starts :/

Comment: @BartlomiejSkwira: `manual` worked for me when I had to use it (no auto-start). About _disable_ or _disabled_, the startup shell script (see `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions`) doesn't really care, if it's not `auto` it doesn't start.

Comment: According to the source `/usr/share/postgresql-common/PgCommon.pm` it's also spelled _disabled_ so the manpage is indeed wrong.

Comment: This never worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. No matter what I placed in `start.conf` (manual, disabled, etc) it always started. I had to completely remove 9.3 to work with an upgraded version of Postgres.

Comment: Changing `auto` to `manual` also works on machines running `systemd`. Just remember to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing the file.

Answer (score 0):

1. variant:
   set postgresql cluster to manual and disabling of postgresql service.

1.1. to set the postgresql cluster to manual mode:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo sed -i 's/^auto$/manual/' /etc/postgresql/12/prod/start.conf
```

1.2. check it is done well:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ cat /etc/postgresql/12/prod/start.conf
# Automatic startup configuration
#   auto: automatically start the cluster
#   manual: manual startup with pg_ctlcluster/postgresql@.service only
#   disabled: refuse to start cluster
# See pg_createcluster(1) for details. When running from systemd,
# invoke 'systemctl daemon-reload' after editing this file.

manual
```

1.3. after editing you will have to update:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

After this command, the service rereads start.conf and updates its configuration, so there is no need to forcibly disable it (section 1.5).
You can check this:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl is-enabled postgresql@13-main.service
disabled
```

1.4. to stop postgresql cluster service:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ systemctl stop postgresql@postgresql@12-prod.service
```

1.5. If you missed section 1.3, or it failed to disable of postgresql service:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ systemctl disable postgresql@postgresql@12-prod.service
```

What does it look like:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl is-enabled postgresql@12-prod.service
disabled

robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl is-enabled postgresql.service
enabled

robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl is-enabled postgresql@.service
indirect
```

PostgreSQL cluster 13-main in autostart, unlike PostgreSQL 12-prod:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl is-enabled postgresql@13-main.service
enabled-runtime

robert@debian-pg:~$ tail -1 /etc/postgresql/13/main/start.conf
auto
```

Autorun of PostgreSQL 12-prod disabled:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl status postgresql@12-prod.service
● postgresql@12-prod.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-prod
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled;     vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

PostgreSQL 12-prod is in manual mode:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ cat /etc/postgresql/12/prod/start.conf
# Automatic startup configuration
#   auto: automatically start the cluster
#   manual: manual startup with pg_ctlcluster/postgresql@.service only
#   disabled: refuse to start cluster
# See pg_createcluster(1) for details. When running from systemd,
# invoke 'systemctl daemon-reload' after editing this file.

manual
```

To start  postgresql 12-prod cluster manually, simply:

```
robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl start postgresql@12-prod.service

robert@debian-pg:~$ sudo systemctl status postgresql@12-prod.service
● postgresql@12-prod.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-prod
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled;     vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-01-22 10:33:18 MSK; 4s ago
    Process: 1516 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-    redirect 12-prod start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1521 (postgres)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 2307)
     Memory: 25.5M
        CPU: 1.391s
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-postgresql.slice/postgresql@12-    prod.service
             ├─1521 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D     /var/lib/postgresql/12/prod -c     config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/prod/postgresql.conf
             ├─1524 postgres: 12/prod: checkpointer
             ├─1525 postgres: 12/prod: background writer
             ├─1526 postgres: 12/prod: walwriter
             ├─1527 postgres: 12/prod: autovacuum launcher
             ├─1528 postgres: 12/prod: stats collector
             └─1529 postgres: 12/prod: logical replication launcher

Jan 22 10:33:13 debian-pg systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 12-    prod...
Jan 22 10:33:18 debian-pg systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL Cluster 12-prod.
```

Answer (score -1):

Rename /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/posgtgresql.conf to something else, or move the entire  /etc/postgresql/9.1 directory somewhere else.

The start scripts key off of the directories that exist in /etc/postgresql/ that have */postgresql.conf in them.

Comment: Renaming or even moving postgresql.conf and start.conf isn't enough and the server still starts. Moving the dir works, but seems more like a bad workaround.

Comment: It won't start w/o a postgresql.conf... it'll SAY it does, because the startup scripts on ubuntu are horrible about giving any sort of useful output about what is going on, but the server doesn't start:(((

    for c in /etc/postgresql/"$2"/*; do
        [ -e "$c/postgresql.conf" ] || continue
)))(read: no error output)

Moving the entire directory removes the configuration from the startup script detection completely and then it shouldn't mention it.